# Is there a library for working with SharePoint 2007 RPC web services?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, rpc

I'm trying to develop a client app that works with SharePoint 2007 remotely via its [RPC web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587481%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  Does anyone know of a library, preferably .Net, which wraps these RPC calls?

Comment: http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/